# Ubuntu slower than Windows 10

Tags: 19.04

I recently installed **Ubuntu 19.04** on my laptop (6th gen i5, 8gb RAM  and AMD r5 m335 graphics) and found that Ubuntu boots much slower than Windows 10 did. It nearly takes me **1:20** mins to boot into the desktop. Plus the apps are slow to open for the first time. Did I do something wrong with the install?

Comment: What's the output of `systemd-analyze blame`? [Edit] your question to include the output of this command.

Comment: Do both OS use the same drive hardware? I've seen folks keep Windows on their SSD, install Ubuntu to a data HDD, and then wonder why Ubuntu seemed slower.

Comment: Were you using Windows **Fast Boot**? It is the default usually.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think you menat **Fast Startup**? Usually the default indeed. Fast Boot is a UEFI  feature.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes I did mean **Fast Startup** for Windows 10. `fastboot` is also a linux program for Intel chipsets to eliminate display flicker during boot: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-DRM-Fastboot-Yet-Again. `fastboot` is also an Android Tool for Linux: https://blog.sombex.com/2018/01/install-adb-and-fastboot-easiest-way-on-linux-mint-ubuntu-debian-based.html `fastboot` is also a grub parameter to skip `fsck` all the time (I use this): https://my.esecuredata.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/110/skip-or-permanently-bypass-fsck-check-on-linux